# npm run dev without error ,but console `template or render function not defined`

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I had a strange vue problem yesterday,`NPM run dev` implementation success, but the console prompt `template or render function not defined.`, looking for information, has not been solved, hope to get help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S96Yi.png)

project address: https://github.com/shunzizhan/vue/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both `App.js` and `App.vue`. and inside `main.js` you do `import App from './App'`. I think it is importing 'App.js`, which indeed does not have a template or render function. Try removing`App.js` and you should be good.